# How to limit table rows and don't append blank row while dynamic feed data?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I write a simple talbe demo that limit table row count is 10.The table work fine and the row count is 10 that it is what I wanted.The problem is that while new data exceeded 10 rows, the `TableView`  will also append a blank row to it endlessly, this is not I wanted.Can someone know how to do or give any opinions or solutions?

**The Code Demo**

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

TABLE_MAX_LINE = 10

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self._data = []
        self._columns = list("ABCD")

    def appendData(self, oneRecord):
        dataLen = len(self._data)

        self.rowsAboutToBeInserted.emit(QModelIndex(), dataLen, dataLen)
        # self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._data.append(oneRecord)
        # self.layoutChanged.emit()
        self.rowsInserted.emit(QModelIndex(), dataLen, dataLen)

        # print(dataLen, TABLE_MAX_LINE)
        if dataLen > TABLE_MAX_LINE:
            del self._data[0]

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._columns[section]
        elif orientation == Qt.Vertical and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return f"{section}"

    def rowCount(self, parent) -> int:
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent) -> int:
        return len(self._columns)

    def data(self, index, role: int):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data[index.row()][index.column()]


app = QApplication([])

v = QTableView()
v.show()
model = Model()
v.setModel(model)

def appendData():
    import random
    r = lambda: random.randint(1, 10000)
    model.appendData([r(), r(), r(), r()])

timer = QTimer()
timer.setInterval(1000)
timer.timeout.connect(appendData)
timer.start()
app.exec()
```

**The Effect**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're emitting the insert row signals *before* checking if the data length is bigger than what's allowed.

While, theoretically, logic would say that it *should* work, it's not a good implementation and doesn't work fine with Qt item views implementation, which use some internal mechanisms for optimizations and cannot keep up if the "size" of the data model doesn't match. The most important aspect to keep in mind is that a view *always* calls `rowCount()` whenever new rows has been added, and the `rowsInserted` signal won't match the actual row count, because at that point the length of `self._data` is bigger.

In order to properly implement the wanted behavior, the following points must be followed:

- don't directly emit the signals, but use the existing functions: [`beginInsertRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) and [`endInsertRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#endInsertRows), which will take care of *properly* update the model, and the linked views by emitting the above signals when appropriate and with proper arguments;
- call the above functions **only** when a row is actually inserted;

Considering the above, whenever the model has reached the maximum row count, it will *not* add new rows (since no row is actually added), but will emit the [`dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal to ensure that the *shifted* indexes will correctly use the new data:

```
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    # ...
    def appendData(self, oneRecord):
        dataLen = len(self._data)
        if dataLen <= TABLE_MAX_LINE:
            self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), dataLen, dataLen)
            self._data.append(oneRecord)
            self.endInsertRows()
        else:
            del self._data[0]
            self._data.append(oneRecord)
            self.dataChanged.emit(
                self.index(0, 0), 
                self.index(dataLen - 1, len(self._columns) - 1)
            )
```

Note that if you want to keep the view correctly updated (and you probably should), the index should also be updated along with the changed model, so a *better* solution would be to remove the first row in the model if the row count has reached the maximum, and then append a new row *anyway*:

```
class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    # ...
    def appendData(self, oneRecord):
        dataLen = len(self._data)
        if dataLen > TABLE_MAX_LINE:
            self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0)
            del self._data[0]
            self.endRemoveRows()
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), dataLen, dataLen)
        self._data.append(oneRecord)
        self.endInsertRows()
```

In this way, if an index is selected, the selection will be correctly updated (moved up) whenever a new row is added and the maximum row count has been reached.

Comment: In `QAbstractItemModel` model it's  better to use  `Protected Functions` instead of `Signals`.So I also want to know  what's time we should use `Signals`, both them seems work, but  `Protected Functions` work better.

Comment: @jie basically, if a class already provides a function that *also* emits the signal, you should use the function, because it usually gets "all the job done": for models this is very important, because those functions do not only emit signals, but also, and most importantly, ensure that the persistent indexes of the model are correctly kept updated.